# Custom field on managed package

Tags: apex, managed-package, deployment, fields, eclipse

There are 2 custom fields  that are created on activity object in managed package. when i am deploying from one sandbox to other using eclipse not able to do it.

**problem:Only components in the same namespace as the organization can be created through the API**
 If i go and create manually field on Activity object it is not adding that field 
to particluar name space

Comment: Sound like you are deploying to the wrong organization or using the wrong namespace

Comment: Just to be clear - you don't deploy managed package components from a Sandbox to another - you install the package in each sandbox...

Comment: I have installed package components in sanbox. but i want to create a custom fields that should be in this namespace